# Rails log levels to files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, log-level

I want to log warn messages to a file like warn.log, error messages to a file like error.log.
I've googled so many pages and also the StackOverFlow, but I didn't find some parallel topics.
Do you have any good suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this gem [multi_level_logger](https://rubygems.org/gems/multi_level_logger)

Add the following in your `config/environments/production.rb`

```
config.logger =  MultiLevelLogger::MLogger.create(:all=>true)
```

Now your logs will be written into separate files. And your default logger will be disabled.

For more info check [here](https://github.com/tak2siva/multi_level_logger)